# javascript error in online host (print script)

Tags: javascript, jquery

problem about doing it online , it works  fine in localhost

i have this code 
its prints the specific div by div id

```
    function printDiv(divID) {
        //Get the HTML of div
        var divElements = document.getElementById(divID).innerHTML;

        //Get the HTML of whole page
        var oldPage = document.body.innerHTML;

        //Reset the page's HTML with div's HTML only
        document.body.innerHTML ="<html><head><title> </title></head><body>"+divElements + "</body>";

        //Print Page
        window.print();

        //Restore orignal HTML
        document.body.innerHTML = oldPage;
}
```

it works beautiful in my localhost

but when i upload the file to my onlinehost it show like this picture

[image shows the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieX40.png)

can someone help me what is the error  ?

Comment: You want to set html and head part in body, really?

Comment: to add some text for print page ,and not showing them in the main page

Comment: Ya but BODY element cannot content HTML and HEAD elements, you would anyway duplicate these elements and of course this is invalid HTML markup. And the dupe link is exactly what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: i will try moving html and head , and will let body only

Comment: No remove body, it would be invalid too... You just need: `document.body.innerHTML = divElements;`. But be aware, reseting itto original content once printed, you'll lose all binded events/datas (if not delegated to document level). I'd instead just hide all elements without a specific class using e.g: `@media print {:not(.toPrint){display: none;}}`. And: `function printDiv(divID) {$('#' + divId).addClass('toPrint'); window.print(); $('#' + divId).removeClass('toPrint');}`

Comment: ok thanks man , i will try doing it

Comment: Forget about media print, i made mistake in rule